# Can the jmp instruction jump to any part of the code?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

can the jmp instruction go back to a previous block of code like the one below will label1 be executed infinite times or not ?

```assembly
    label1:

      mov ax,10
      add ax,2

    jmp label1
```

Comment: You could try it, or you could read your textbook.

Comment: @ShmilTheCat but when i'm doing it the control moves back to the main proc it doesn't even stay in the same one

Comment: @AndrewLazarus i have tried it and i have tried searching it but it doesn't give a clear explanation

Comment: @CSStudent , as Andrew said, devote some time reading your text book, you may also want d/l this PRM and read it http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html (chapter 5 instruction set summary, focus on control transfer instructions)

Comment: Since your real problem is that your program isn't doing what you should expect it to you should post your complete program (or a minimal complete verifiable example that reproduces the problem if your program is too big) and explain both what it should be doing and what it's actually doing instead.

Comment: you guys will just simple down vote on that as well so i'll probably not :)

Comment: Then I would suggest deleting your question and asking for help elsewhere. We can't help you if you're not willing to say what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

A simple jmp instruction can jump to any part of the code (between the current segment; Also known as JMP NEAR).
A conditional jump can only jump between 128 bytes back and 127 bytes forward (relative to the current position; also known as JMP SHORT).
The third version of the jmp instruction is JMP FAR which could jump to any offset in any segment.(JMP FAR is only possible in 16-bit Realmode and Kernelmode)